# (iOS/Objective-C) Better way of conditionally adding different buttons to a UIActionSheet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

In my iOS app, I'm presenting a UIActionSheet to a user; however the UIActionSheet has to be able to present different buttons for different cases (e.g. if user is not running iOS 5, then Twitter support is unavailable, so don't show the "Tweet this" button; if AirPrint is unavailable, then user can't print, so don't show the "print" button, etc.)  Right now I have this implemented in a really brain-dead fashion, basically using a bunch of if-then-else statements (see below).  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController"))  {
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Options", @"Options string")
                                                             delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button")
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open in Safari", @"Open in Safari button"), NSLocalizedString(@"E-mail to a Friend", @"E-mail to a Friend button"), NSLocalizedString(@"Print", @"Print button"), NSLocalizedString(@"Tweet This", @"Tweet This button"), nil];
    } else {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Options", @"Options string")
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button")
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open in Safari", @"Open in Safari button"), NSLocalizedString(@"E-mail to a Friend", @"E-mail to a Friend button"), NSLocalizedString(@"Print", @"Print button"), nil];
    }
} else {
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Options", @"Options string")
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button")
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open in Safari", @"Open in Safari button"), NSLocalizedString(@"E-mail to a Friend", @"E-mail to a Friend button"), NSLocalizedString(@"Print", @"Print button"), nil];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about as simple as you're gonna get using `addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title`:

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Options", @"Options string")
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button")
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open in Safari", @"Open in Safari button"), NSLocalizedString(@"E-mail to a Friend", @"E-mail to a Friend button"), NSLocalizedString(@"Print", @"Print button"), nil];

if(NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController"))
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Tweet This", @"Tweet This button")];
```

Comment: That's a lot better than what I had before. :) Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure the button indexes are still what you expect after adding the additional button.

Comment: That turns out to be quite easy.  `addButtonWithTitle` returns an `NSInteger` that is the index of the button just added.  So you can do something like `myButtonIndex = [myActionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Some Title"];`; then later in the delegate method, you can test to see if `index == myButtonIndex`, etc.

Comment: Very nice - i didnt realize addButtonWithTitle returned an NSInteger.  Maybe I should read my documentation more carefully. :-D

Comment: In iOS 7, this is causing the new option to be added after 'Cancel'.